# I am one of many kinds

Tags: riddle

I am one of many kinds

Some say my opposite are all the same

For that others say I'm cray

I can like my kin

I can like their kin

I can be a former them

And they a former me

Kids ask why I'm hurt

For I bleed 48 times every leap

But my role no longer is to sweep

Who are I, and who are they?

Comment: Quick hint, Who are I is not a grammatical mistake, but an hint itself

Comment: DId you mean to tag it quizz?

Comment: Definently not, I meant riddle. Thanks for the heads up =)

Comment: I don't understand why this question was down-voted, seems like a legitimate riddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am one of many kinds

Some say my opposite are all the same

For that others say I'm cray

> men are all alike / women are crazy

I can like my kin

I can like their kin

I can be a former them

And they a former me

> homosexual / heterosexual / transgender

Kids ask why I'm hurt

For I bleed 48 times every leap

> leap *year*
>  (actually this line was the giveaway)

But my role no longer is to sweep

> feminism

Who are I, and who are they?

> Women and men. 
>  (But I don't get the grammatical mistake clue, so maybe I'm missing something.)

Comment: This was my first thought as well. My thought on the last clue: Eggs are gender-less until conception (ie both).

Comment: Yes, I thought the leap was gonna be a dead giveaway =)
As per the last hint, it wasn't anything special, just that rather than a woman/men I meant women/men. Feminism was a nice one, but I was expecting equal rights ;P